# Stackoverflow AddIn for VisualStudio, Eclipse

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, addon

What do you think about this idea.

This addin will give you the ability to browse for questions and what is more important to type answers directly inside your IDE.

This way you can write some code, compile it, add some simple text and submit your answer to stackoverflow.com

Or there is something similar created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like the idea. If we have RSS feeds in Visual Studio (@Downvoter - although we can have it in the browser also :), or search boxes in editors like UltraEdit,  I don't see why this would be a bad idea.

Which is not to say it's absolutely neccessary(!), but a nice idea nevertheless.

*Don't think I saw anything like that mentioned as of yet, though ... sorry :(*

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, it's really quite unnecessary

Having a visual studio **and** a browser opened consumes too much memory for you?

Comment: what? you can run more than one application at once? did someone upgrade your iPad?

Comment: @jeff - that would be jailbreak, not upgrade...

Comment: @Downvoter, sometimes it's more like a competition, who answers first gets more points. So time matters I believe.